# Native Queries in ReactiveMongoRepository

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query

Is there a way to perform native queries in ReactiveMongoRepository like JpaRepository which uses @Query annotation? Likes this:

```
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyClass, Long> {
@Query(value= "SELECT id FROM my_table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1" , nativeQuery = true)
public Long getRandomData();
}
```

This is the query I want to perform:

```
db.airportControl.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "$and": [
      { "$expr": { "$eq": [{ "$year": "$boardingDate" }, 2019] }},
      { "airportDestiny": "MAD"}
    ]
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "average": {
      "$avg": { "$subtract": ["$boardingDate", "$securityGateDate"] }
    }
  }}
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries.json-based

And this:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries.aggregation

```
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudReppsitory<Person, String> {

  @Aggregation("{ $group: { _id : $lastname, names : { $addToSet : $firstname } } }")
  List<PersonAggregate> groupByLastnameAndFirstnames();                            

  @Aggregation("{ $group: { _id : $lastname, names : { $addToSet : $firstname } } }")
  List<PersonAggregate> groupByLastnameAndFirstnames(Sort sort);                   

  @Aggregation("{ $group: { _id : $lastname, names : { $addToSet : $?0 } } }")
  List<PersonAggregate> groupByLastnameAnd(String property);                       

  @Aggregation("{ $group: { _id : $lastname, names : { $addToSet : $?0 } } }")
  List<PersonAggregate> groupByLastnameAnd(String property, Pageable page);        

  @Aggregation("{ $group : { _id : null, total : { $sum : $age } } }")
  SumValue sumAgeUsingValueWrapper();                                              

  @Aggregation("{ $group : { _id : null, total : { $sum : $age } } }")
  Long sumAge();                                                                   

  @Aggregation("{ $group : { _id : null, total : { $sum : $age } } }")
  AggregationResults<SumValue> sumAgeRaw();                                        

  @Aggregation("{ '$project': { '_id' : '$lastname' } }")
  List<String> findAllLastnames();                                                 
}
```

These are for Spring Data Mongo, but they should also apply to ReactiveMongoRepository, because:

> 15. Reactive MongoDB repositories
>
> This chapter describes the specialties for reactive repository support for MongoDB. This chapter builds on the core repository support explained in [repositories]. You should have a sound understanding of the basic concepts explained there.